# ProGuard breaks javascript access to my Java applet

Tags: java, javascript, browser, applet, proguard

I have a jar-file which is loaded into a browser as an applet. On the webpage, there are several javascript instances which inform the Java applet what to do.
But after obfuscating the .jar file with ProGuard, this no longer works.
The browser console gives me the following error:

`Object #HtmlAppletElement has no method 'example'`

This is the Java code:

> public void example(int i){
>
> dosomething();
>
> }

Works fine without ProGuard obfuscation - I tried many different settings in ProGuard. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [Processing callback methods](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#callback) in ProGuard's manual:

> #### Processing callback methods
>
> If your application, applet, servlet, library, etc., contains callback methods, which are called from external code (native code, scripts,...), you'll want to preserve them, and probably their classes too. They are just entry points to your code, much like, say, the main method of an application. If they aren't preserved by other `-keep` options, something like the following option will keep the callback class and method:
>
> ```
> -keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
>     void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
> }
> ```
>
> This will preserve the given class and method from being removed or renamed.